# Help me out with real-life Gamma distributions

Tags: survival, gamma-distribution, poisson-process

I'm working with some data relating to maintenance and parts failures. I've got a pure math background with only a little bit of probability, and I'm currently learning by doing.

I've got a list of parts (all the same), with dates and reasons why they were replaced. Some were replaced due to failure, others for preventive maintenance. I calculated the time in days between replacement and separated it by reason. When I make a histogram of times between replacement due to failure, I get something that looks convincingly like a negative exponential distribution. However, when I make a histogram of times between replacement due to PM, I get a hump that indicates a gamma distribution.

Now I know it's possible that I made bad histograms, but my intuition tells me there's something going on here, because there's something else strange going on. One would expect the mean time between replacement due to PM to be less than that due to failure, because a part replaced due to failure has lived its entire lifespan, while a part replaced due to PM has not. However, in this case the opposite is true: parts replaced due to PM tend to have had a much longer lifespan. I can think of some reasons why this might be the case, but the difference in distributions leads me to believe there's an underlying cause that can be described mathematically. I can't manage to figure that out, though. Can anyone shed some light on this, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Given that there is a PM program, the failures you observe do not reflect the full failure-time distribution: these would only be the failures that are "surprises," because they occur sooner than expected.  This seems to be a salient reason to consider when looking for an explanation.  How it might be "described mathematically" depends in part on how the PM is scheduled, how that scheduling might be related to the time each part has been in service, and how maintenance is expected to affect the future lifetime.

Comment: To fill in some details: The part is a belt, and during PM it is either observed to be deteriorated and replaced, or not replaced. PMs are on fixed intervals that are shorter than the average lifetime.

Comment: Continued: Let's call the PM interval "I". So about these "surprise" failures, we can say they either occurred due to an unexpectedly short lifetime (less than I), or otherwise that the time between showing signs of failure, and actually failing (an unknown in general), was less than I.

Comment: If they are not replaced, is something else done? cleanup, oiling (if that is relevant), something else?